# how do i select a menu based on whether user is logged in or not in angular app

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created 2 side drawer menus in angular app which display on different pages within the angular app. Menu 2 includes more links which are displayed when the user logs in. However, if you click on the homepage in the side menu after logging in (which has menu 1 without the logged in extras currently) it logs out and reverts back to the standard menu.

How do I select the menu that displays on each page depending on whether the user is logged in or not? Not everyone will be logging into this app, in fact vast majority wont log in, hence I don't want the homepage to be the login screen.

Any ideas would be hugely welcome! Not sure if you need to see any code I have written but if so just let me know what is relevant. Many thanks

code implemented is:

authentication.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { ToastController, Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from '../../app/services/user';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';


@Injectable( {
 providedIn: "root"
})
export class AuthenticationService {

public isLoggedIn = false;
```

app.component.ts

```
constructor(public authentication: AuthenticationService) {}
```

app.component.html

```
<ion-app>
<div *ngIf="authentication.isLoggedIn">
<ion-split-pane contentId="main-content">
<ion-menu contentId="main-content" type="overlay" menuId="menu">
   <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-menu-toggle menu="menu" auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of 
navigate">
        <ion-item [routerDirection]="'root'" [routerLink]="[p.url]">
          <ion-icon slot="start" [name]="p.icon"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>
            {{p.title}}
          </ion-label>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-menu-toggle>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
<ion-router-outlet id="main-content"></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-split-pane>
</div>
<div *ngIf="!authentication.isLoggedIn">
<ion-split-pane contentId="main-content2">
<ion-menu contentId="main-content2" type="overlay" menuId="menu2">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-menu-toggle menu="menu2" auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of   
 navigate2">
        <ion-item [routerDirection]="'root'" [routerLink]="[p.url]">
          <ion-icon slot="start" [name]="p.icon"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>
            {{p.title}}
          </ion-label>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-menu-toggle>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
<ion-router-outlet id="main-content2"></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-split-pane>
</div>
</ion-app>
```

the menu works for when loading the app but when I login, the menu for when logged out still shows, have I done something wrong above? Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this by using the [angular directive NgIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf). For example:

Create a service component, called **account.service.ts** and store a variable called `isLoggedIn`. Make sure to change this variable depending on whether the user has logged in or not.
Run the command: `ng g s services/account` to generate the service.

**account.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
public export AccountService {
    public isLoggedIn = false;
}
```

In your menu component page, inject the service through the constructor

**menu.component.ts:**

```js
constructor(public account: AccountService) {}
```

Now, in your menu HTML page, do the following:

**HTML**

```html
<div *ngIf="account.isLoggedIn">
    // Your nav bar when the user is logged in.
</div>
<div *ngIf="!account.isLoggedIn">
    // Your nav bar when the user is not logged in.
</div>
```

**NOTE:** Make sure to import `CommonModules` to use the `NgIf` directive.

Comment: Hi Nam, many thanks for the help, much appreciated, if you get a second can you check what I have done above, tried to follow your method and nearly there but missing something. many thanks

Comment: Hi Jon, no worries! Could you tell me what issue you are facing now?

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to implement the code as suggested (have included my code in the question above) but it doesn’t show the logged in menu. So when I start the app (logged out) the correct menu shows, when I log in, it still shows the logged out menu and not the logged in menu? Have I done something wrong? Many thanks in advance

Comment: I have figured it out thanks, the *ngIf statement required isAuthenticated rather than isLoggedin, many thanks for the help!!

Comment: Wish I could upvote this answer twice; byte-for-byte it's the most informative piece of information I've seen on Angular from any source.

Answer (score 0):

Based on you question, you already have a logic how you know if a user is logged in or not.
You can use this logic to display two different menus for logged in and not logged in users. A simple `ngIf` will do the trick. (I assume that the homepage is not the same for logged in and not logged in users).